# Are nested ids okay if necessary -- performance hit or other?

Tags: css, dom, less

I'm using a jQuery-based framework (Kendo UI) which comes with its set of highly selective css rules.

In order to avoid the headache of my css rules clashing (and also to avoid using `!important` all over the place), I've nested everything in a body id -- e.g., `#body-id .my-class`.

However, is there a performance hit or other issue in using:

`#body-id #my-other-id`?

Every resource I find says, "it's pointless and makes no sense semantically."  I agree, however, as I'm using the Less CSS framework, my entire CSS stylesheet will be wrapped in `#body-id` (for simplicity sake).  Thus, it would eventually compile to `#body-id #my-other-id` (I'm assuming).

Comment: I'd say that anything used to avoid `!important` is fine. I don't see any *significant* / *notable* performance issues other than the fact that it will be hard to overwrite these specific styles. If it is really necessary, as your title implies; then it's fine.

Comment: see also: http://lesscss.org/#-namespaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery selector speed is not very important, because there are other more narrow bottlenecks in your browsers JavaScript implementation.

Only if you have many, many jQuery operations like this to perform, the speed performance will be an issue

But by the way jQuery analyzes the selector (from right to left) an id with child selectors does not profit from javascript getElementById speed.

So it's more or less not important. But it may be not good style.
Check, if your CSS code is modular!

### Edit

Here is a 'official' resource on performance and else
http://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/